# VSCode with ElectronJs: Debuging working but console.log is not logging

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

I am trying to debug the electron.js application with VSCode. In order to do that, I have made the given below `launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": null,
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}\\node_modules\\electron-prebuilt\\dist\\electron.exe",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                ".",
                "--enable-logging"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "address": "localhost",
            "restart": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": null
        }
    ]
}
```

**Problem**

The debugger is stopping at the break points however the `console.log` is not printing in debug console.

but the debug console is not empty. Its saying...

```
'c:\Users\Vikas\Desktop\electron apps\todoElectron\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\electron.exe' --debug-brk=36967 . --enable-logging main.js
```

Please help. Many thanks.